# use mixins as class names in stylus

Tags: javascript, css, stylus

I'm a beginner to stylus and am working on a project with vue to create a small component library. I wanted to know if there was a way to use mixins as class names to achieve the following:

```
<style lang="stylus"> // this is where the stylus code is written.
bgColor (argument)
  background-color: argument
</style>
```

Then I would use this in the HTML template as:

```
<div class="bgColor(ff0000)"></div>
```

What I'm basically trying to achieve is a simple way to mimic atomizer (https://acss.io/guides/atomizer.html) using stylus.

I'm also open to any other way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Stylus is a pre-processor language, even on Vue it isn't dynamic after compiling.

But you can archieve that by generating every color option as a class.

```
<style lang="stylus">
colors = ( ff0000, ff00ff ) // color collection
for color in colors
  .bgColor\({color}\)
    background-color unquote('#' + color)
</style>
```

Comment: This would be too cumbersome, I went with CSS variables route since it was way easier to manage. Thanks for your time though!